# What's the communication complexity of round-change in Quorum's QBFT implementation

Tags: quorum, consensus, ibft, qbft

As stated in [the Istanbul BFT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.03613.pdf), Istanbul BFT "has O(n^2) communication complexity during both normal case operation and round changes". [The QBFT spec](https://entethalliance.github.io/client-spec/qbft_spec.htm) also states a "message complexity of O(n^2)".

But when I read the go-quorum code, I notice that each `qbfttypes.RoundChange` object, which will be encoded into RLP format and broadcast to all peers, contains a list of prepare message named as `Justification`. The list contains at least a quorum of prepare messages, which have a number of O(n). A quorum or O(n) validators need to broadcast ROUND-CHANGE to start the new round, and a message broadcast will be gossiped to O(n) validators. So I get a message complexity of O(n^3) here. I wonder whether there are mistakes in my calculation or the go-quorum code doesn't implement the QBFT spec.